# How to change/filter the data range dynamically based on slicer value?

Tags: powerbi

recently I am comparing the accuracy of a model.
This model has lots of version, V1,V2,V3.....
Each of the version contains values in different month, for example:
V1 (Jan - March)
V2 (Feb - April)
V3 (March - May)
..
..
..

The data is connected with a date table.

Also, it is a daily model, and the model may contain 0 value. In order to show to 0 value, I have use `isblank` then 0 function to display the 0 value like below:

[image]

However, as I mentioned above, V1 only contains the data from Jan - Mar, so, when I tried to use slicer to filter other version (e.g. Apr - Jun), as the function forced to display 0 value, there is a horizontal line in the graph like below:

[image]

It makes the line chart very hard to read. Thus, I want to automictically filter the date range to suitable date range when I click the slicer (e.g. When I select V1, it only displays Jan - Mar).

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do your table data in aggregated mode? I mead for each version there is single row per date?

Answer (score 0):

If I guess your table name is **your_data_table_name** and you have these below columns-

```
Date
version
value

...and other columns
```

Now you can create a new table from your source table **your_data_table_name** using this below **M Qquery** in **Power Query Editor**.

**Note** change table name with your table name from the below code.

```
let 
    Source = #"your_data_table_name",
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Date", "Version"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Version"}, {{"min_date", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable date}, {"max_date", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Duration.Days([max_date] - [min_date]) + 1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each List.Numbers(1, [Custom])),
    #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1"),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom.1", "Custom.2", each Date.AddDays([min_date], [Custom.1] - 1)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"min_date", "max_date", "Custom", "Custom.1"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"Version", "Custom.2"}, your_data_table_name, {"Version", "Date"}, "your_data_table_name", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded your_data_table_name" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "your_data_table_name", {"Value"}, {"your_data_table_name.Value"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded your_data_table_name",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"your_data_table_name.Value"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"Custom.2", "Date"}, {"your_data_table_name.Value", "Value"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

You will have this below data finally-

[image]

**Now** you can create you **slicer** (single selection on) from the new table. Also create the line chart using **Date** and **Value** columns from the new table. Final output will be as below-

[image]